# CodeIgniter: Sessão recriada após o recarregamento da página

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

Tenho um sistema aonde uma sessão é criada para o usuário após o seu login, o problema é que cada acesso que faço ao site uma nova sessão é criada e os dados gravados são apagados, configurei a sessão como autoload e as configurações são:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'nomequalquer';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

esse é o código de login:

```
$user = $this->user_model->doLogin($_POST);
if($user != false){
    $this->session->set_userdata(array('logged' => true, 'user' => $user));
    $_SESSION['sess_id'] = session_id();
    echo json_encode(array('1', $_SESSION));
}else ...
```

Envio os dados da sessão para gravar eles no console do chrome, o redirectionamento é feito aqui:

```
...
function(data, status, jqXHR){
    if(status == 'success'){
        ...
        var result = JSON.decode(data);
        //debugging
        console.log(result[1]);
        //redirecionamento
        windows.location.replace = <?php echo "'" . base_url(array('admin/usuarios')) . "'"; ?>;
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Na página `some/page` eu coloquei um botão que acessa o seguinte código no servidor:

```
$_SESSION[session_id()] = 'hello!';
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

é possível ver que o id da sessão se altera a todo momento e os dados inseridos no login não existem mais. Qual seria o motivo disso?

Comment: pq vc mistura a sessão do php padrão com a do CI?

Comment: porquê na documentação diz que eu posso fazer assim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse é o segundo dia com esse problema, a única solução que eu encontrei foi utilizar a biblioteca nativa do php, copiei essa library: [Native session](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Native-session) que faz uso dela, além disso ela é mais apropriada pro meu caso porque não salva as informações no computador do usuário.